# ViewBag on a Javascript code mvc 4

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having a trouble doing this: I have a ViewBag that contains the list of documents Id's and the response time for each one, created like this:

**Controller**:

```
ViewBag.Documents= (from n in db.DocumentType
                     select new {a = n.DocumentTypeId, b=n.ResponseTime});
```

Based on the document that the user selected on a dropdownlist, the javascript code calculates the real duration of processing the document (duration).

```
DocumentId(int)          Response(int)
    1                     2 days
    2                     3 days
    3                     1 day
```

The complete javascript code calculates the final date based on response time without weekends and holidays, but the only part that it is not working is the following part of JavaScript code:

**JavaScript at the view:**

```
function CalculateTime(documenttype) {
                var duration= 0;
                var jScriptArray= new Array();
                var array = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Documents))';
                for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                        jScriptArray [i][j] = array [i][j];
                    }
                }
                for (i = 0; i < jScriptArray.length; i++) {
                   if (documenttype== jScriptArray [i][0]) duration= jScriptArray [i][1];
                }
                return duration;
            }
```

I already have the correct `documenttype` variable based on a dropdownlist but this script is not working. I think is the way I want to use the ViewBag, but I am not pretty sure. What I need to know is: what is wrong with my code or another way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should encode it to JSON before you send it to the ViewBag.

Comment: It's because your JavaScript variable `array` is set to a string value by using quotes around the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine helped me solve my problem. Some of you told me to use Json, so we did this:

**Controller:**

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

...

var timeList= db.DocumentType.ToList();

ViewBag.ResponseTimes= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                {
                    times= (from obj in timeList
                               select new { DocumentTypeId= obj.DocumentTypeId, ResponseTime= obj.ResponseTime})
                }, Formatting.None));
```

**JavaScritp at the View:**

```
function CalculateTime(documenttype) {
                var duration = 0;
                var jScriptArray = new Array();
                var array = $.parseJSON(@Html.Raw(ViewBag.ResponseTimes));
            for (i = 0; i < array.times.length; i++) {
                if (parseInt(documenttype) == array.times[i].DocumentTypeId) {
                    duration= array.times[i].ResponseTimes;
                }
            }
            return duration;
        }
```

Thanks!

PS: I don't know which of both answers give the acceptance cause we used part of both....

Answer (score 3):

Just remove quotes

```
 var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Documents));
```

Comment: TypeError: array is null at the Web Developer console

Comment: @ASP_beginner, Debug your application and see what controller action puts in `ViewBag.Documents` and then do a `console.log(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Documents)))`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the quotes(') and you have to Newtonsoft.Json for this.

```
var array = @Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.Documents);
```

This will work.

Comment: Even if there is a syntax error in the ";" in the above code, this will work perfectly.

Comment: If i remove the quotes shows me array as null. if I use the quotes with that statement... shows me TypeError: "jScriptArray[i] is undefined" at the Web Developer console.

Comment: You need to add Newtonsoft.Json.dll in your project for that statement to run.